# RandomAccessFile not reading integer correctly

Tags: java

I am trying to read a binary file using RandomAccessFile in Java.

The problem is -- it's not returning the proper values. If you take a look at this sceencap of Hex Workshop with my file open:

[image]

You'll see that the first 4 bytes are 82 if you read them as int32.

My program, yet, is reading them as 1375731712 when I call:

```
raf.readInt();
```

It seems to me like my program is reading these bytes backwards (something endian related?).

How can I read them properly and how is Hex Workshop knowing which endianness to use?

Answer (score 0):

Java is reading int as a big-endain, but it is written to file as little-endian.

```
1375731712 -> 01010010 00000000 00000000 00000000 (big-endian)
82         -> 00000000 00000000 00000000 01010010 (big-endian)

1375731712 -> 00000000 00000000 00000000 01010010 (little-endian)
82         -> 01010010 00000000 00000000 00000000 (little-endian)
```

Wikipedia: [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: According to that entry, If I read corretly, this file of mine is Big Endian, right? And I am reading them as Little Endian. How come Hex Workshop is reading them properly? And how can I read them properly in Java?

Comment: @MichelReap Yes, sorry. By mistaken those two with each other. My intuition toward endianness is not working.

Comment: @MichelReap there is no endianness in the file per se; it is your debugger which reads as little endian. Little endian is also LSB, or Least Significant Byte (first)

Comment: @fge there is endianness in how int is encoded in a file. And it's not a debugger it's a hex-viewer.

Comment: There is some implicit endianness in the file in the sense that `52000000` is supposed to mean 82 and not 1375731712 (I know this because this 32 bit integer is an offset position on the screen). Funny thing is, using a .NET app I am now converting to java, I can read the file properly, while I read some little-endian files as well without a problem. How is this possible?

Comment: @NiematojakTomasz no there isn't; it is only the way you read which determines endianness. The file doesn't care, it just has bytes.

Comment: @MichelReap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078100/fast-reading-of-little-endian-integers-from-file