# Reading File in Little Endian, without reading into bytebuffer? [Java]

Tags: java, nio

I want to read a file in little endian. The solutions I've found for this are using a bytebuffer and storing the data I want to read in there. However the file I want to read could potentially be huge, 100GB let's say. I assume attempting to allocated a byte buffer of that size is not a good idea to read the data from.

So what is an efficient way of reading data from a file in little endian without loading the data physically into a byte buffer? Is there a way to perform the way byte buffer reads just to something general like a RandomAccessFile?

I'd appreciate any assistance.

Comment: You don't have to store the entire file in a single ByteBuffer in order to use one. You can read the data in convenient sized chunks of, say 4096 bytes, and process that chunk before reading in the next chunk. Have you actually read any of the Javadocs for InputStream or any of its subclasses?

Comment: I would look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078100/fast-reading-of-little-endian-integers-from-file